# get selected file object with react-hook-form

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-hook-form

I have a component which uploads a file. When an image is selected it previews it in another component.

So, when an image is selected,  I need to access it. I tried using `getValues()` and `watch()` from `react-hook-form` but it is returning me path of the file in string form not the file object.

```
          <div className="photo">
            <Avatar
              src={
                // it gives path of the file as string
                getValues('photo')
                  ? URL.createObjectURL(getValues('photo')[0])
                  : "https://icon-library.com/images/no-image-icon/no-image-icon-0.jpg"
              }
              alt="photo preview"
              sx={{ width: "200px", height: "200px" }}
            />
            <label htmlFor="contained-button-file">
              <Controller
                name="photo"
                control={control}
                render={({ field }) => (
                  <Input
                    {...field}
                    accept="image/*"
                    id="contained-button-file"
                    type="file"
                    error={Boolean(errors["photo"])}
                    helperText={errors["photo"]?.message}
                  />
                )}
              />
              <Button variant="contained" component="span">
                Upload
              </Button>
            </label>
          </div>
```

Somehow, `watch()` and `getValues()` reading value of `input` field here. While they should be returning `e.target.files` instead.

It can be checked [here](https://dev.to/coder4_life/upload-files-with-react-hook-form-m4j) and [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hook-form-uploadfile-with-thumbnail-preview--drag-and-drop-p11gy?file=/src/FileInput.jsx), It works the same way. It returns the files.

Why it does not return files but returning value here?

Answer (score 0):

Using work around for now. Using [setValue()](https://react-hook-form.com/api/useform/setvalue) and calling it on change of the input file.

```
          <div className="photo">
            <Avatar
              src={
                watch('photo')
                  ? URL.createObjectURL(watch('photo')[0])
                  : "https://icon-library.com/images/no-image-icon/no-image-icon-0.jpg"
              }
              alt="photo preview"
              sx={{ width: "200px", height: "200px" }}
            />
            <label htmlFor="contained-button-file">
              <Input
                accept="image/*"
                id="contained-button-file"
                type="file"
                error={Boolean(errors["photo"])}
                onChange={(e) => setValue("photo", e.target.files)}
                multiple
                helperText={errors["photo"]?.message}
              />

              <Button variant="contained" component="span">
                Upload
              </Button>
            </label>
          </div>
```